# Git submodule that is not versioned by parent project?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule in the folder `Styles/`.

If I commit to the submodule, I will also see a change in the parent project because of a
changed head version.

However, nothing can be less interesting to the parent project that changes has been done in the submodule. The other developers only cares about changes in the parent project.

How do I separate the submodule from the parent project so you will not need to commit a changed git hash of its head into the parent project?

(There is no git hash for the specific module in the .gitmodules file).

```
[submodule "Styles"]
    path = Styles
    url = https://foobar.se/test/Styles
```

## edit

I tried this

```
[submodule "Styles"]
    ignore = all
    path = Styles
    url = https://foobar.se/test/Styles
```

and now, the Styles folder does not appear in the list of changes even if the submodule version has been changed. However there seems to still be a super-project-pointer when I check the submodule log (a commit in the submodule that the super project points to).

Comment: The parent project has to know which commit to check out when you initialize the submodule, I think that is what's happening with that. People move to package management (like Nuget) instead of submodules to "just get the current version", because of these little annoyances with submodules.

Comment: Would be great to automatically have the newest version of a given branch. Isnt that supported by submodules then?

Comment: I have always had to push the parent git repo when changing the submodule, but I haven't looked too deep into it because there are better solutions for that. The problem always checking out the newest version could have a new bug. Meanwhile your checked out version does not have it and leads to "works on my machine" arguments. Knowing that a specific commit will always be checked out is the counter-measure for that. I would say you can instead have `Styles` in gitignore and blindly clone the repository into there. In a team with just a few people that can be good enough.